# Check-box should not be marked/unmarked when the sheet is protected

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I am trying to make a macro that adds a new checkbox when new data is inputed, but it should only be marked or unmarked when the sheet is unprotected. I tried to do this with the following code:

```
Range("Z4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LOOKUP(2,1/(C[-15]<>""""),ROW(C[-15]))"
i = Range("Z4").Value + 1

    Cells(i, 19).Select
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(Cells(i, 19).Left, Cells(i, 19).Top, 60.75, 15).Select
    With Selection
            .Value = xlOff
            .LinkedCell = Cells(i, 30)
            .Display3DShading = False
    End With
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Pagado"
```

Where the linked cell is locked and therefore should not be able to be changed when locked.

Otherwise, the rest of the code works perfectly.

Comment: Ty, sorry for the errors

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? Side note: you generally want to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad The issue is that I require that the checkbox is not marked or unmarked while the sheet is protected. But, in order to avoid the manual configuration of setting up the linked cell, I am looking for a way where when the code adds a new checkbox, it links it with the cell located at the same row but column 30, but the code is not doing so right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out by doing this, was easier that I thought. It was a matter of adding two strings together and then protecting the sheet and locking the referenced cells.

```
Cells(i, 19).Select
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(Cells(i, 19).Left, Cells(i, 19).Top, 60.75, 15).Select
With Selection
        .Value = xlOff
        .LinkedCell = "$CC$" & i
        .Display3DShading = False
End With
Selection.Characters.Text = "Pagado"
```

Hope it can help someone else.